# Why does app allocated memory permanently increase when showing fragments or starting activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory, memory-management

I'd like to ask the community what they think about this behavior.

On my main activity I have one FloatingActionButton that when clicked will show a DialogFragment.

I followed Google's guidelines (I can't link it due to being a new user here at Stack Overflow) on how to properly create a DialogFragment so I believe I'm OK there. I've tested this behavior on fragments that use either onCreateDialog and onCreateView, and in both cases the results are the same.

When I click the button and I look at the memory usage, this is what I see:

[Memory when fragment is first showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo0en.png)

So Android is allocating additional resources to compensate for showing a new fragment. That makes sense to me.

However, when I dismiss or cancel the dialog, the allocated memory doesn't drop.

When I open the same dialog using the same button, the allocated memory jumps again. I repeat this over and over (red arrows) until my allocated memory reaches just under 10MB and then (I believe) the Garbage Collector (blue arrow) kicks in and cleans up the app:

[Memory after multiple showings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MztHu.png)

To me, this means I'm relying on the Garbage Collector to do the work for me and from what I understand that is not good practice.

Can anyone tell me if this is normal Android behavior, or is there something I'm doing wrong? If It isn't normal behavior, I will try to resolve the issue myself first before asking the community for further assistance (this is why I did not provide any code).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this excerpt from [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) sums up this behavior nicely.

> Android does not offer swap space for memory, but it does use paging and memory-mapping (mmapping) to manage memory. This means that any memory you modify—whether by allocating new objects or touching mmapped pages—remains resident in RAM and cannot be paged out. So the only way to completely release memory from your app is to release object references you may be holding, making the memory available to the garbage collector. That is with one exception: any files mmapped in without modification, such as code, can be paged out of RAM if the system wants to use that memory elsewhere.

Basically, all you can do as an app developer is to release references to objects you allocate. So assuming you aren't keeping a reference to the object anywhere, like placing the fragment on the back stack for later use, the reference to the object should be released when the fragment is closed. At this point, it is available to the garbage collector to clear the previously allocated memory.

After that is done, it is up to the garbage collector to decide when to come in to action, so to say.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to validate some logic with you if you don't mind: Assuming my code is correct, the references to the objects within the fragment are correctly being released once the fragment closes. However, due to Android managing memory using mmapping, we will not see a drop in RAM unless the garbage collector successfully runs. If and when it does, there should be a drastic decrease in memory. I can assume everything is working correctly if I indeed see this drop in RAM when the collector clears it up. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yeah, your logic sounds correct. Unfortunately I don't know enough low level details to explain what happens in depth, and I cannot say for sure whether your app is behaving normally. However, with the information you gave, it sounds like everything is working as expected.